# Download Mac OS X SDKs for 10.9 and 10.10 in Xcode 7

Tags: macos, xcode7

Is it possible to download and build against Mac OS X 10.9 and 10.10 SDKs on OS X 10.11 using Xcode 7?

Comment: Do you mean setting the target platform in your project settings? You can make your application support any version of Mac OS.

Comment: Sure, just set the Deployment Target and Base SDK in the Project Build Settings

Comment: No, I need to test against the actual SDK for methods that aren't supported in them and other general behavior.  I have the deployment target set to 10.9.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it is possible, the [XcodeLegacy](https://github.com/devernay/xcodelegacy) script is a popular way to automate this.

Or you can do it manually, you need to put `MacOSX10.9.sdk` (or a symlink to it) into `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs`. Note you'll need to replace it every time you update Xcode, so the symlink is a good idea.

Comment: Where can I find these other SDKs for download?  I only have MacOSX10.11.sdk in that folder.

Comment: You need to get them out of old Xcode versions, the XcodeLegacy script will download and extract them. Or download old Xcode versions from http://developer.apple.com/downloads and extract them manually.

Comment: Or, @BerryBlue, you can get SDKs from [GitHub - phracker/MacOSX-SDKs: A collection of those pesky SDK folders: MacOSX10.1.5.sdk thru MacOSX10.11.sdk](https://github.com/phracker/MacOSX-SDKs)

Comment: If you're using TimeMachine, you can also easily reach back into previous versions of Xcode you may have installed (and deleted) to get the previous MacOS SDK folders.  In my case, I simply did `open /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs` in Terminal (which opens a Finder window) and then opened Time Machine to get back to a date where the SDK I was looking for existed.